# USB devices including Android phone stopped working

Tags: networking, usb, mouse, ethernet, android

This is odd. I noticed my Android phone wouldn't work (share files, charging was fine). Then suddenly the network stopped working. I have been away for a few weeks and returned a couple of days ago. Tried using the PC yesterday and the issue was still there - so using my laptop to upload this.

I've tried updates and all sorts, but as expected nothing works as there is no network. Googling and forums, but nothing works so far

Can anyone help? I'll try and type some cmd outputs below:

uname -r [CODE]6.2.0-1005-oracle[/CODE]

This first included networking, but I managed to get that working.  The issues are now just the USB Mouse, USB memory stick and Android phone.